# Give Date validation In android

Tags: android, android-layout

In android i am trying to adding validation but it not working i want to give validation to date. following is the code for date.

My datformat is=MM/dd/yyyy

```
 private static final String DATE_PATTERN =
            "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [/.-] (0?[1-9]|1[012]) [/.-]  ((19|20)\\d\\d)";
 String getdatefor = fromDateEtxt.getText().toString();
                String datefors = toDateEtxt.getText().toString();
                matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(getdatefor);
                matchers = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(datefors);
                if(matcher.matches()&&matchers.matches()){

                    new AsyncLoadSales().execute(getdatefor, datefors);

                }


//Birthday validator
                else if (!matcher.matches()){
                    fromDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                    toDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");

                }
                else{
                    fromDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                    toDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                }
```

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this without using pattern.

```
private static final String DATE_PATTERN =
            "(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)";
 String getdatefor = fromDateEtxt.getText().toString();
                String datefors = toDateEtxt.getText().toString();
                if(getdatefor.matches(DATE_PATTERN)&&datefors.matches(DATE_PATTERN)){

                    new AsyncLoadSales().execute(getdatefor, datefors);

                }


//Birthday validator
                else if (!getdatefor.matches(DATE_PATTERN)){
                    fromDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                    toDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");

                }
                else{
                    fromDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                    toDateEtxt.setError("Please Enter Valid Date");
                }
```

Comment: its work but by default i want to set "/" after two digits only digits are deletable dont delete this "/" symbol is there any solution for this